# Passing image to tflite model

Tags: tensorflow, flutter, deep-learning, tensorflow-lite

I loaded tensor-flow Lite model in Flutter but i am having some problem passing the image to the model for prediction. The prediction method allows any object to pass but Flutter is reading images as Files as i am using Image Picker class and I cant find a way to convert file type into an image so that i can convert it into a (28,28,1) which is required by the model.

Thanks, any help would be appreciated.

```
Uint8List imageToByteListFloat32(
       img.Image image, int inputSize, double mean, double std) {
    var convertedBytes = Float32List(1 * inputSize * inputSize * 3);
    var buffer = Float32List.view(convertedBytes.buffer);
    int pixelIndex = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < inputSize; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < inputSize; j++) {
        var pixel = image.getPixel(j, i);
        buffer[pixelIndex++] = (img.getRed(pixel) - mean) / std;
        buffer[pixelIndex++] = (img.getGreen(pixel) - mean) / std;
        buffer[pixelIndex++] = (img.getBlue(pixel) - mean) / std;
      }
    }
    return convertedBytes.buffer.asUint8List();
  }

  classifyImage(File image) async {
    var output = await Tflite.runModelOnBinary(
        binary: imageToByteListFloat32(image, 224, 127.5, 127.5),// required
        numResults: 10,    // defaults to 5
        threshold: 0.05,  // defaults to 0.1
        asynch: true      // defaults to true
    );
    setState(() {
      _loading = false;
      _outputs = output;
    });
  }`
```

Comment: Please format your code properly

Comment: Hello Rizwan, and welcome to Stack Overflow. I tried fixing your formatting, but the process might have upset the indentation. Once it's approved please make sure I've got it right.

Comment: Does anyone knows how to use the `img.getRed` in the new versions of the image library.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the flutter image lib to get an image from a file.

```
import 'package:image/image.dart' as imageLib;
var image = imageLib.decodeImage(await imageFile.readAsBytes());
```

Also this github repo from shaquian might be helpful for you!

https://github.com/shaqian/flutter_tflite/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart